# div doesn't show up with textarea angular+

Tags: html, angular, textarea

This is my html, I am using angular but not sure if my mistake is very simple or if I'm crazy lol. I've put a div around the textbox and positioned it rel while the textbox is abs, the background is supposed to be in the div and the textbox is supposed to go on top of it. I didn't apply it directly to the textbox which I've tried and worked, however it is an issue for my text, the text goes off the colored background.

**HTML**

```
<div class='email'>
    <p> Have Questions?
    </p>

    <form>
        <div class='backg'>
            <input placeholder='Name:'>
        </div>

        <div class='backg'>
            <input placeholder='Email:'>
        </div>

        <div class='mess'>
            <textarea class='message' placeholder='Message'>
            </textarea>
        </div>

    </form>


</div>
```

This is my **scss** which is not very good.
I am still a beginner at 18, so could you give me some pleasant advice.

**scss**

```
 .email {
     width:100%;
     height:400px;

     p {
         width:100%;
         height: 30px;
         font-size: 20px;
    }

    .backg {
        height: 60px;
        background-image: url('/assets/images/back.png');
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        width: 80%;

        input {
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
            text-indent: 50px;
            color: black;
            border:none;
            background-color: transparent;
            font-size:15px;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-family: monospace;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: +5;

        }
    }

    .mess {
        width:40%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height:150px;        
        background-image: url('/assets/images/back.png');
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }


    .message {
        width:100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: +5;
        height:150px;
        color: red;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-indent: 50px;
    }


    ::placeholder {
        color: black;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size:15px;
        font-family: monospace;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out: background-color: transparent; apparently the background-default is white and it was covering the div. but why doesn't the div show that it exists?